# How to update openshift application which does not receive automatic updates?

Tags: python, flask, openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge

I'm trying to figure out how install security updates for my OpenShift application.

It's a community created openshift 'flask' framework which does not seem to receive automatic updates:
https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/116-flask

I've tried to follow https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/upgrading/manual_upgrades.html#install-config-upgrading-manual-upgrades but none of the yum commands work.

```
\>  yum install atomic-openshift-utils
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a python app so you need to say what are it's dependencies from the **setup.py** file.

Put it in there and fill the link to pypi where to find it

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    # GETTING-STARTED: set your app name:
    name='YourAppName',
    # GETTING-STARTED: set your app version:
    version='1.0',
    # GETTING-STARTED: set your app description:
    description='OpenShift App',
    # GETTING-STARTED: set author name (your name):
    author='Your Name',
    # GETTING-STARTED: set author email (your email):
    author_email='example@example.com',
    # GETTING-STARTED: set author url (your url):
    url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
    # GETTING-STARTED: define required django version:
    install_requires=[
        'Flask==0.11,
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        'https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/',
    ],
 )
```

Comment: I don't think this helps with the operating system security updates like Linux kernel, ssh, OpenSSL etc. I need to make sure that host VM is updated.

Comment: No, you don't have admin privileges on that machine and it's been managed by OpenShift, you can't use admin tools. The only way to install dependencies is specifying in setup.py or requirements.txt.

You can read how to run a Flask app [here](https://developers.openshift.com/languages/python/flask.html#step2)